# error when trying to install laravel package socialite

Tags: laravel, composer-php, laravel-5.3, laravel-socialite

I am getting the following error when trying to install socialite package in Laravel when I try to run `composer require laravel/socialite`. Why does this error occur?

> Problem 1
>
> - Conclusion: remove laravel/framework v5.3.30
> - Conclusion: don't install laravel/framework v5.3.30
> - laravel/socialite v3.0.0 requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.9].
> - laravel/socialite v3.0.2 requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.9].
> - laravel/socialite v3.0.3 requires illuminate/http ~5.4 -> satisfiable by illuminate/http[v5.4.0, v5.4.13, v5.4.9].
> - don't install illuminate/http v5.4.0|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.30
> - don't install illuminate/http v5.4.13|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.30
> - don't install illuminate/http v5.4.9|don't install laravel/framework v5.3.30
> - Installation request for laravel/framework (locked at v5.3.30, required as 5.3.*) -> satisfiable by laravel/framework[v5.3.30].
> - Installation request for laravel/socialite ^3.0 -> satisfiable by laravel/socialite[v3.0.0, v3.0.2, v3.0.3].

Comment: Your error tells you clearly your version of Socialite requires Laravel 5.4. But you are using Laravel 5.3

Answer (score 1):

In console:

```
composer require laravel/socialite:~2.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error states you need Laravel 5.4 to work with the version of socialite you are installing. You can target a lower version of socialite by adding the following to your composer.json file:

```
"laravel/socialite": "~2.0"
```

Then run `composer update`